# How do I change navbar logo and styling dynamic?

Tags: mdriven

I am building a multi tenant platform and want to have different logos and styling of the navbar depending on logged in user or some other business rule. How do I do that?

If I want to add widgets on the navbar, for example notification indicator, how do I do that?

Answer (score 0):

An interesting possiblity is to make a component, and that component includes a /style tag that is data-bound. You can also include base64 coded images that is used by the css in your component.

For inserting stuff in the navbar maybe you can use pseudo elements from CSS.

Otherwise I would install a local Turnkey development like this https://wiki.mdriven.net/index.php/Development_in_Visual_Studio. Then you can change any part of the site.